# Dynamic Package.json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, heroku, npm

I'm working on a nodejs project with multiple private dependencies to GitHub in the `package.json`, like so:

```
"dependencies" : {
   "mymodule":"git+https://<token>:xoauthbasic@github.com/my_github_account/my_repo.git#<commit-ish>"
}
```

I have two problems here:

1. I don't want the oAuth token apart of my `package.json` file, for security.
2. I want the branch I use for dependencies to be dependent on the environment it is built in. For example: In a production environment, use #master, and in a development environment, use #development.

Are there any solutions to these problems? In addition, it'd be great if the solutions worked with Heroku.

Comment: As for security token, I would recommend you to use `ssh` authentication instead. It's safer and you don't have to include any credentials in you `package.json`.

Comment: The problem with `ssh` authentication is that it doesn't seem to work with Heroku. When asked, they said to use the token instead.

Comment: I'm not a Heroku user and not familiar with it's workflow, but [this looks pretty much what you need to setup `ssh` authentication](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/debitoor/ssh-private-key-buildpack).

Comment: Anyway, all you have to do to setup `ssh` is to add a particular private key to your Heroku instance before running `npm install` command. Doesn't sound hard to me.